# How to check duplicate records in a table having 20 columns without primary key in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

I have a table having more than 20 columns and i need to find the duplicate records from the table from all the columns without any primary key.
While trying to write all the column names and then run the query ,it doesnt returns any output as the no of records may be too large.
Suggest a way to resolve this query

Comment: How many records do you have, and are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Decide on the database you are using. Add sample data and expected result

Comment: There are many good answers about finding duplicate values. Have you tried searching?

Comment: I am using oracle database

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), column1, column2, column3, ..., column20 FROM Employee GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, ..., column20 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If there are millions or billions of records, this may take an extremely long time to run, but assuming there are not more than a few thousand duplicate entries across all 20 columns, the number of output rows should be manageable to return.

Comment: I have tried this but getting no output as the duplicate records are too many in bulk.